# COM (Component Object Model) Insert Comment in MS Office

Tags: com, ms-word, ms-office, autohotkey

I have used AHK and COM to do various things inside Microsoft word. For example, I have been able to write a script that finds and replaces or highlights words.  However, I have not been able to find documentation on how to use COM to create or delete a comment in office.

I know that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178796.aspx is the documentation on how to add comments in C# and VBA, but how would I do this using COM.

Answer (score 0):

When I answered this question I was unable to test the code at the time. I've edited it to better reflect what you asked and demonstrate a working example.

> Create a COM Object Word Application

```
oWord := ComObjCreate("Word.Application")
```

> Create a new Document.

```
oWord.Documents.Add
```

> Add Text to our document.

```
oWord.Selection.TypeText("AutoHotkey is a pretty cool scripting language.")
```

> Now lets add our comment

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(oWord.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range
                                  , "This is a very true statement!.")
```

> Make our document Visible

```
oWord.Visible := 1
```

> Set a Hotkey to Delete the Comment. (Windows Key + F1)

```
#F1::oWord.ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Delete
```